# OpenCV digits merging into surrounding boxes

Tags: python, c++, opencv, computer-vision, imagemagick

I've got a bunch of dates i'm trying to OCR using tesseract.
However, a lot of the digits in the dates merge with the lines in the date boxes as so:

---

[image: Digits intersecting boxes]
[image: Digits intersecting boxes]
[image: Digits intersecting boxes]
[image: Digits intersecting boxes]

---

Also, here's a good image that i can tesseract well with:
[image: Good Date Image]

---

And here's my code:

```
import os
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import subprocess
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

def show(img):
    plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
    plt.imshow(img,cmap='gray')
    plt.show()

def sort_contours(cnts, method="left-to-right"):
    # initialize the reverse flag and sort index
    reverse = False
    i = 0

    # handle if we need to sort in reverse
    if method == "right-to-left" or method == "bottom-to-top":
        reverse = True

    # handle if we are sorting against the y-coordinate rather than
    # the x-coordinate of the bounding box
    if method == "top-to-bottom" or method == "bottom-to-top":
        i = 1

    # construct the list of bounding boxes and sort them from top to
    # bottom
    boundingBoxes = [cv2.boundingRect(c) for c in cnts]

    cnts, boundingBoxes = zip(*sorted(zip(cnts, boundingBoxes),
        key=lambda b:b[1][i], reverse=reverse))

    # return the list of sorted contours and bounding boxes
    return cnts, boundingBoxes


def tesseract_it(contours,main_img, label,delete_last_contour=False):
    min_limit, max_limit = (1300,1700)
    idx =0 
    roi_list = []
    slist= set()
    for cnt in contours:
        idx += 1
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        if label=='boxes':
            roi=main_img[y+2:y+h-2,x+2:x+w-2]
        else:
            roi=main_img[y:y+h,x:x+w]

        if w*h > min_limit and w*h < max_limit and w>10 and w< 50 and h>10 and h<50:
            if (x,y,w,h) not in slist: # Stops from identifying repeted contours

                roi = cv2.resize(roi,dsize=(45,45),fx=0 ,fy=0, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
                roi_list.append(roi)
                slist.add((x,y,w,h))

    if not delete_last_contour:
        vis = np.concatenate((roi_list),1)
    else:
        roi_list.pop(-1)
        vis = np.concatenate((roi_list),1)

    show(vis)

    # Tesseract the final image here
    # ...


image = 'bad_digit/1.jpg'
# image = 'bad_digit/good.jpg'
specimen_orig = cv2.imread(image,0)


specimen = cv2.fastNlMeansDenoising(specimen_orig)
#     show(specimen)
kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.uint8)

# Now we erode
specimen = cv2.erode(specimen, kernel, iterations = 1)
#     show(specimen)
_, specimen = cv2.threshold(specimen, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
#     show(specimen)
specimen_canny = cv2.Canny(specimen, 0, 0)
#     show(specimen_canny)

specimen_blank_image = np.zeros((specimen.shape[0], specimen.shape[1], 3))
_,specimen_contours, retr = cv2.findContours(specimen_canny.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE )
# print(len(specimen_contours))
cv2.drawContours(specimen_blank_image, specimen_contours, -1, 100, 2)
#     show(specimen_blank_image)
specimen_blank_image = np.zeros((specimen.shape[0], specimen.shape[1], 3))

specimen_sorted_contours, specimen_bounding_box = sort_contours(specimen_contours)

output_string = tesseract_it(specimen_sorted_contours,specimen_orig,label='boxes',)
# return output_string
```

---

The output from the good image attached is so:
[image: Good output]

---

Tesseracting this image does give me accurate results.

However, for the ones where the lines are merging into the digits, my output looks like this:
[image: bad1]
[image: bad2]
[image: bad3]
[image: bad4]

These do not work well with Tesseract at all.
I was wondering if there was a way to remove the lines and keep only the digits.

I have tried the following as well:
https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d1/dee/tutorial_moprh_lines_detection.html

Which doesn't really seem to do great on the images i've attached.

I've also tried to use imagemagick:

```
convert original.jpg \
\( -clone 0 -threshold 50% -negate -statistic median 200x1 \)  \
-compose lighten -composite                                    \
\( -clone 0 -threshold 50% -negate -statistic median 1x200 \)  \
-composite output.jpg
```

Its results are fair, but the line removed somewhat cuts through the digits as following:

[image: imagemagick1]
[image: imagemagick2]
[image: imagemagick3]
[image: imagemagick4]

Is there a better way i can approach this problem? My final goal is to tesseract the digits, so the final image does need to be quite clear.

Comment: Aren't the characters an the preprint in different colors ?

Comment: Nope, they're all binary. Black and white.

Comment: I would avoid tesseract and go for MNIST. Maybe it works a lot better

Comment: But MNIST is handwritten digits. These are a font. And Tesseract does a really good job. It just needs a cleaner image.

Comment: Looks like your font is the same? If this is the case, tr template matching on all 10 numbers

Comment: That is a really good idea. Although, i still do need to know if this kind of an image cleanup is possible using OpenCV or even Imagemagick.

Comment: is this binary image your original source image, or you have already done some thresholding operation on it ? It would a little easier to solve if the input was in colored format.

Comment: The binary image is the original source. No color unfortunately.

Comment: Do all the images contain the same box layout?

Comment: Yes they do :)
The image shifts a little sometimes and the digits can merge into the boxes.

Comment: Is a C# solution ok (methods names are basically the same so it's quite easy to port to other languages)?

Comment: Yes, that's fine :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is some code that seems to work quite well. There are two phases:

- One can observe that numbers are slightly bolder than boxes. Plus the whole image has strong horizontality. So we can apply a dilatation stronger horizontally to get rid of most vertical lines.
- At this point, OCRs, for example, [Google's one](https://cloud.google.com/vision/), can detect most numbers. Unfortunately, it's somewhat too good and sees other stuff, so I have added another phase that is more complex and quite related to your particular context.

Here is one image's result after 1st phase:

[image]

And here are all results after 2nd phase:

[image]

As you see it's not perfect, 8 can be seen as B (well, even a human like me sees it as a B... but it can be easily fixed if you have only numbers in your world). There is also like a ":" character (a legacy from a vertical line that has been removed) that I can't get rid of either w/o tweaking the code too much...

The C# code:

```
static void Unbox(string inputFilePath, string outputFilePath)
{
    using (var orig = new Mat(inputFilePath))
    {
        using (var gray = orig.CvtColor(ColorConversionCodes.BGR2GRAY))
        {
            using (var dst = orig.EmptyClone())
            {
                // this is what I call the "horizontal shake" pass.
                // note I use the Rect shape here, this is important
                using (var dilate = Cv2.GetStructuringElement(MorphShapes.Rect, new Size(4, 1)))
                {
                    Cv2.Dilate(gray, dst, dilate);
                }

                // erode just a bit to get back some numbers to life
                using (var erode = Cv2.GetStructuringElement(MorphShapes.Rect, new Size(2, 1)))
                {
                    Cv2.Erode(dst, dst, erode);
                }

                // at this point, good OCR will see most numbers
                // but we want to remove surrounding artifacts

                // find countours
                using (var canny = dst.Canny(0, 400))
                {
                    var contours = canny.FindContoursAsArray(RetrievalModes.List, ContourApproximationModes.ApproxSimple);

                    // compute a bounding rect for all numbers w/o boxes and artifacts
                    // this is the tricky part where we try to discard what's not related exclusively to numbers
                    var boundingRect = Rect.Empty;
                    foreach (var contour in contours)
                    {
                        // discard some small and broken polygons
                        var polygon = Cv2.ApproxPolyDP(contour, 4, true);
                        if (polygon.Length < 3)
                            continue;

                        // we want only numbers, and boxes are approx 40px wide,
                        // so let's discard box-related polygons, if any
                        // and some other artifacts that passed previous checks
                        // this quite depends on some context knowledge...
                        var rect = Cv2.BoundingRect(polygon);
                        if (rect.Width > 40 || rect.Height < 15)
                            continue;

                        boundingRect = boundingRect.X == 0 ? rect : boundingRect.Union(rect);
                    }

                    using (var final = dst.Clone(boundingRect))
                    {
                        final.SaveImage(outputFilePath);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's amazing! Thanks a lot! :)
Also, could you tell me how i could extract the digits if they touch the top or the bottom horizontal lines? Like in the case of an image as such:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/o4swx5821v5qea7/4K1CDD61780143.jpg?dl=0

Comment: @MetalloyD - hmmm... this case is harder, even for a human. The numbers may be possibly matching exactly the horizontal line. What you can do if nothing was found (= if the final bounding rect area is too small for example) is change the 40 width check by something bigger, like 100. It will get you back something a bit better. Google OCR almost finds it.

Answer (score 2):

Just a suggestion, I never tried that.

Instead of trying to remove the bars, keep them and train on all possible bar positions. Trim the bars to the character limits for proper alignment.

[image]
[image]

Train these as `02032018022018`. I guess it is better to simulate the bars on clean characters.

Comment: I'd probably try going with an object detection route a little later. I was just wondering if this kind of images clean up is possible using OpenCV. Because I have a lot of such images. This is just a particular use case :)

Answer (score 0):

In particular, look at your `1` in `2018` below in the case of Yves Daoust casus... that's almost an `"n"` or as three-quarter of the integer `0` and the `8` becomes the letter `B`. The `2` can be read as inverted `6`. In some cases `0` can been read as `6` as well, etc..  Even some might ends up as "unrecognizable" if you leave the grid in place. Thus my approach would be:

1. Taking out the redundant grid-info helps with a better identification of integers that have straight lines within them like `0,1, 2, 4, 5` and `7`.
2. Followed by character training using Cascade classifier.

The curvatures in some digits are easily detected once the grid is removed and training is done. This will reduce 90-95 percent of your false negative hits into either real integers (true positives) or bogies (true negatives). You then only have to worry about those 5-10 percent.

Docs and sample code info can be found [here at OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/dc/d88/tutorial_traincascade.html), [here at Code-Robin](http://coding-robin.de/2013/07/22/train-your-own-opencv-haar-classifier.html) and [here at github](https://github.com/mrnugget/opencv-haar-classifier-training).

Image values `02032018022018`:

[image: values 02032018022018]